# What happened to Milton?

Tags: what-remains-of-edith-finch

For most of the characters in the game, there's good indication of what really happened to them...

Except for Milton.  As far as I could tell, his disappearance just went completely unexplained.

Did I miss some important detail?  What happened to Milton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer for what happened to Milton, but this answer is not found specifically within the story of *What Remains of Edith Finch*. Understanding Milton's story requires familiarity with the developer's previous game *The Unfinished Swan*. Creative Director Ian Dallas confirmed [in a reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/67hhyx/giant_sparrowian_dallas_what_remains_of_edith/dgqoa4f/?context=3) that Milton is more-or-less canonically a character in that game, which has unusual implications for Edith Finch's world.

Comment: Thanks!  With this information I was able to find [this article](http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2017/04/26/what-remains-of-edith-finch-easter-egg-is-canon/) which explained more.